# When and how to use a template literal operator?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, c++14, user-defined-literals

On [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal#Literal_operators) there is a mentioning that one can have *templated* user-literal operators, with some restrictions:

> If the literal operator is a template, it must have an empty parameter list and can have only one template parameter, which must be a non-type template parameter pack with element type `char`, such as

```
template <char...> double operator "" _x();
```

So I wrote one like in the code below:

```
template <char...> 
double operator "" _x()
{
    return .42;
}

int main()
{
    10_x; // empty template list, how to specify non-empty template parameters?
}
```

**Question:**

1. The code works, but how can I use the operator with some non-empty template parameters? `10_x<'a'>;` or `10_<'a'>x;` does not compile.
2. Do you have any example of real-world usage of such templated operators?

Comment: I've never seen that before, but it looks like the idea is to treat the characters before the prefix as `char`s at compile-time, rather than treating it as a numeric literal and passing it to a run-time function.

Comment: @KyleStrand But I'm still not sure how you use it (i.e., compile it with no errors).

Comment: Obviously I'm not either, since I've never seen it before! But I do have a working example I've just written, so I'll post that.

Comment: @KyleStrand Ohh I meant compiling successfully (not why one would use it).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> ```
> 10_x; // empty template list, how to specify non-empty template parameters?
> ```

That isn't quite right. The template parameter list isn't empty. When you write:

```
template <char... Cs> 
??? operator "" _x()
```

The `Cs` get populated from the stuff on the left-hand side of the literal. That is, when you write:

```
10_x
```

that calls:

```
operator ""_x<'1', '0'>();
```

One simple example would be to build a compile time, overflow-safe binary literal such that:

```
template <uint64_t V>
constexpr uint64_t make_binary() {
    return V;
}

template <uint64_t V, char C, char... Cs>
constexpr uint64_t make_binary() {
    static_assert(C == '0' || C == '1', "invalid binary");

    return make_binary<2*V + C - '0', Cs...>();
}

template <char... Cs> 
uint64_t operator "" _b()
{
    static_assert(sizeof...(Cs) <= 64, "overflow");

    return make_binary<0, Cs...>();
}

uint64_t a = 101_b; // OK: a == 5
uint64_t b = 102_b; // error: invalid
uint64_t c = 11111111110000000000111111111100000000001111111111000000000011111111110000000000_b; // error: overflow
```

Comment: Ohhh I see, yes, makes perfect sense, as the operator itself takes no arguments... But it seems there's absolutely no way to access those `char`s.

Comment: @vsoftco What do you mean? They're just like any other template non-type parameter.

Comment: I mean they don't have a name, so I cannot pull them out directly inside the operator. But @Kyle's example clarifies it a bit. Ok, now I see more scenarios in the comments, I realized you can name them.

Comment: @vsoftco You could just name them.

Comment: @vsoftco Also didn't realize that I failed to actually copy in the make binary example...

Comment: The nice thing about those is that with the right `constexpr` functions it allows you to diagnose overflow at compile time.

Answer (score 7):

Your template parameters are *already* specified--they're *the source-code characters comprising your literal value*! So for `10_x`, you're actually calling:

```
template<> double operator "" _x<'1', '0'>();
```

Here's a working example. It compiles without error, and none of the assertions are triggered.

```
#include <cassert>

enum class MyEnum
{
  ONE,
  TWO,
  THREE
};

template<char...> MyEnum operator "" _e();

template<> MyEnum operator "" _e<'1'>()
{
  return MyEnum::ONE;
}
template<> MyEnum operator "" _e<'2'>()
{
  return MyEnum::TWO;
}
template<> MyEnum operator "" _e<'3'>()
{
  return MyEnum::THREE;
}

int main()
{
  assert(1_e == MyEnum::ONE);
  assert(2_e == MyEnum::TWO);
  assert(3_e == MyEnum::THREE);
}
```

Comment: That's a nice example! So the only way to *access* the `char`s are via specializations.

Comment: No, you could also do for example `template<char... Cs> const char* operator "" _cs() { static const char arr[] = {Cs..., '\0'}; return arr; }`

Comment: @aschepler It took me a while to realize why you can re-initialize the `static`: because you have different operators for each template parameter.

Comment: @vsoftco Right, so it's not truly re-initialization--it's separate initialization of separate `static` values. I'm sure there are other clever tricks as well...

Answer (score 2):

You can elaborate the parameters pack somehow (as mentioned by others) or access them as a compile-time string if you prefer:

```
template<int N>
constexpr double f(const char(&str)[N]) { return .42; }

template <char... C> 
constexpr double operator "" _x()
{
     return f({C...});
}
```

> Do you have any example of real-world usage of such templated operators?

You can use the above mentioned technique to deal with compile-time *string-to-num* converter and have something like `10_x` instead of `f("10")` or whatever.

Comment: You can't write `warrior_x`.

Comment: @Barry Fair enough. Fixed. I ever forget the (let me say) _constraints_ on literal operator templates. Thanks.