# Does C++17 allow a non-ascii character as an identifier?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, standards, c++17, user-defined-literals

At [cppref](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal), I find a strange C++ code, which uses a non-ascii character in source code as follows:

```
template <char...> double operator "" _π(); // OK
```

However, the code above cannot be cmompiled with clang 6.0. The error message is:

```
error : source file is not valid UTF-8
1>double operator "" _<A6><D0>()
1>                    ^
```

My questions are:

1. Is this conforming to C++17?
2. Note that user-defined `_π` has no argument, then, how to use `_π`? Just use `double var = _π;`?

Comment: [Unicode characters in identifiers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/identifiers#Unicode_characters_in_identifiers)

Comment: I think the key element here is that the `<char...>` would represent the set of characters used with the literal, which essentially takes the place of the argument. So `2.5_π;` would call `operator "" _π()` with the template arguments `<'2','.','5'>`.

Comment: The pi character works OK https://ideone.com/6AGIX0 What environment (os, shell) are you using? A6D0 doesn't look like valid UTF-8 encoding for pi.

Comment: A6 D0 is not a UTF-8 sequence.  Check your editor or IDE to ensure you are saving your source file as UTF-8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the link you provided, it quotes:

> If the literal operator is a template, it must have an empty parameter
>   list and can have only one template parameter, which must be a
>   non-type template parameter pack with element type char

```
template <char...> double operator "" _x();
```

Let us see what this means,

Notation `char...` indicates that this template can be instantiated with 0, 1, 2 or more parameters of type `char`. This means that each time the compiler encounters a literal like `1234_km` it should treat it as the following function call:

```
operator"" _km<'1', '2', '3', '4'>();
```

The entire string representing the literal is passed (chopped) as template argument. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39795893/when-and-how-to-use-a-template-literal-operator?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) and [this](https://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2012/10/23/user-defined-literals-part-ii/) for usage.

And regarding the range of characters allowed:(See this [Annexure E](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf))

```
00A8, 00AA, 00AD, 00AF, 00B2-00B5, 00B7-00BA, 00BC-00BE, 00C0-00D6, 00D8-00F6, 00F8-00FF
0100-167F, 1681-180D, 180F-1FFF
200B-200D, 202A-202E, 203F-2040, 2054, 2060-206F
2070-218F, 2460-24FF, 2776-2793, 2C00-2DFF, 2E80-2FFF
3004-3007, 3021-302F, 3031-303F
3040-D7FF
F900-FD3D, FD40-FDCF, FDF0-FE44, FE47-FFFD
10000-1FFFD, 20000-2FFFD, 30000-3FFFD, 40000-4FFFD, 50000-5FFFD,
60000-6FFFD, 70000-7FFFD, 80000-8FFFD, 90000-9FFFD, A0000-AFFFD,
B0000-BFFFD, C0000-CFFFD, D0000-DFFFD, E0000-EFFFD
```